# Order an Eloquent model by relationship count and then pluck out that count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got this far:

```
return \App\Project::with('likes')->get()->sortByDesc(function($project) {
    return $project->likes->count();
})->lists(['title', 'likes']);
```

And the desired result is:

`array('Some title' => 43, 'Some other title' => 11)`

Is this even achievable with Eloquent? Or should I just build up an array `'manually'`?

***Edit***

Basically, I want to achieve the following:

```
\DB::table('projects')
    ->join('likes', 'projects.id', '=', 'likes.project_id')
    ->select(\DB::raw('title, count(likes.id) as likes'))
    ->groupBy('projects.id')
    ->get();
```

but `Eloquent` way..

I also tried setting `getLikesCountAttribute` method, and now I can do:

`\App\Project::all()->sortByDesc('likesCount')->lists('likesCount', 'title');`

which works fine, but as you can see - this way I have to retrieve all the records first, and then get that count using the magic `getLikesCountAttribute` method. Perhaps not that big of a deal, don't know..

Comment: What does your query return?

Comment: at the moment it returns [null, null, null]

Comment: Try using this: `\App\Project::with('likes')->sortByDesc(function($project) {
    return $project->likes->count();
})->lists(['title', 'likes']);`

Comment: the problem is that `likes` is a relationship method on the model. So basically, the way I see this is that the only way to do this would be by creating a `getLikesCountAttribute` on the model and having that in `lists` array instead..